# Find the same list ID of four tuples in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a procedure...
I have 4 parameters in this procedure.
I want to find the same list ID from a Table using this four parameters.

> With other words, if all IDs have same List_ID then return List_ID, if
>   not return NULL, and admitting that some IDs might be NULL, and some
>   IDs repeats in that table, so it should not fail if ID is null or
>   repeats

The difficult part is that not all the times I have that four IDs set , and I might have only two IDs set and other two set as **NULL**.

For example:

```
Table A
------------------------
ID     List_ID    
------------------------

1        10      
2        10        
3        10         
4        10
```

The only solution I see is something like this:

```
SET id1 = (Select List_ID From Table_A Where ID = _ID_Param1);
SET id2 = (Select List_ID From Table_A Where ID = _ID_Param2);
SET id3 = (Select List_ID From Table_A Where ID = _ID_Param3);
SET id4 = (Select List_ID From Table_A Where ID = _ID_Param4);

#Then I have to check if all ids are same

IF id1 = id2 = id3 = id4 THEN  I found the same List_ID
```

And sometime _ID_Param is set as NULL, so I might have only 1 or 2 or all 4

Sorry If I'm not explaining this very well... but I don't know how to tell this situation, and my knowledges are limited, I need some help

**UPDATE**

this is close to what I need:

```
SELECT 
  IF( (
     MIN( List_ID ) = MAX( List_ID ) 
     AND COUNT( * ) = (Select Count(*) From (SELECT _ID_Param1 AS val
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT _ID_Param2
                     UNION ALL 
                     SELECT _ID_Param3
                     UNION ALL 
                     SELECT _ID_Param4) Temp Where Temp.val is not null 
                 )  ) , List_ID, NULL
   ) AS LID 
FROM table_a

WHERE ID IN ( _ID_Param1, _ID_Param2, _ID_Param3, _ID_Param4 )
```

The Only Wrong thing is that it will return the List_ID even if a parameter not exists in table and there is a duplicate of other parameters And it count it twice. How to exclude such case, to check if all params exists

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one query:

```
select @all_same := (min(List_ID) = max(List_ID) and count(*) = 4)
from table_a
where id in (_ID_Param1, _ID_Param2, _ID_Param3, _ID_Param4);
```

This assumes that each `id` is unique in `table_a`.  That is how your queries are set up.

Comment: This seems to be close to what I want to do, but what if _ID_Param3 or _ID_Param4 is NULL or NOT NULL ?  should I change count(*) = n, the number of parameters which are not NULL, which I should check using IF NOT NULL and use SET n = n +1 for a global variable  or there is a better way of doing that ?

Comment: Anyway, thank you, it is very close to what I need, I have accepted your answer

Comment: Added an update to my question, please check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COUNT aggregate function to find tuples

```
Select List_ID, COUNT(*) as tuple 
FROM Table_A 
WHERE ID = _ID_Param_1 OR ID = _ID_Param_2 ... etc 
GROUP BY List_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

This will return List_IDs that appears 4 times for a given set of parameters.

Comment: Ok, but what if _ID_Param2 or _ID_Param3 is NULL and not NULL ?

Comment: You can easily handle that with additional OR in the WHERE clause: WHERE (ID = _ID_Param_1 OR _ID_Param_1 IS NULL). Not sure what the implications are for the count, but you can change that number based on number of NOT NULL parameters.